# How can i change the gains of the mic and pcm in android

Tags: android, alsa, mixer, tinyalsa

I  successfully completed the integration of my own aec into android.

But what i need is i have to set the gains of the mic and pcm of the android because in my aec i am applying agc to the farend and nearend signal and then i procees the output of that agc for echo cancelation.

After that i will apply noise reduction on the output of the aec.

When i integrate my aec into the gstreamer there is a command like

> alsamixer

for setting the gain levels.

When i set some gain levels my aec is working fine.

But in android how can i set this to make my aec work well.

Comment: Are you using the ALSA API?

Comment: Dont know that. How to check that?

Comment: Don't you know what your code does? What audio API does it use?

Comment: Then use the tinyalsa mixer API to change the mixer controls. What specific problem do you have with that?

Comment: actually i need to set some gains for mic and speaker to make my aec work. My aec had its own gain controller in it so i need to set outside gain to make it work well

Comment: You already wrote in the question that you want to set the gains. What prevents you from doing that?

Comment: Actually, i dont know how to set the gain levels outside of my aec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mixer_open` to open the control device, find the pointer(s) to your control(s) with the `mixer_get_`* functions, and use `mixer_ctl_set_value` to change it.

See [tinymix.c](https://github.com/tinyalsa/tinyalsa/blob/master/src/mixer.c) for an example.

Comment: I gone through that file and audiohardware.cpp(HAL).
In these files they are calling one fuction 
mixer_ctl_set_value() for setting the mixer related things.
The other thing i noticed is in HAL they are setting volume to 1.0f.
 which one is useful to me?

Comment: Tinyalsa's mixer interface does not have floating-point mixer values.